# Haskell Conduit Aeson: Parsing Large JSONs and filter matching key/values

Tags: json, haskell, aeson, conduit

I have written an application in Haskell that does the following:

1. Recursively list a directory,
2. Parse the JSON files from the directory list,
3. Look for matching key-value pairs, and
4. Return filenames where matches have been found.

My first version of this application was the simplest, naive version I could write, but I noticed that space usage seemed to increase monotonically.

As a result, I switched to `conduit`, and now my primary functionality looks like this:

```
conduitFilesFilter :: ProjectFilter -> Path Abs Dir -> IO [Path Abs File]
conduitFilesFilter projFilter dirname' = do
  (_, allFiles) <- listDirRecur dirname'
  C.runConduit $
    C.yieldMany allFiles
    .| C.filterMC (filterMatchingFile projFilter)
    .| C.sinkList
```

Now my application has bounded memory usage but it's still quite slow. Out of this, I have two questions.

**1)**

I used `stack new` to generate the skeleton to create this application and it by default uses the ghc options `-threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N`.

The surprising thing (to me) is that the application uses all processors available to it (about 40 in the target machine) when I actually go to run it. However, I didn't write any part of the application to be run in parallel (I considered it, actually).

What's running in parallel?

**2)**

Additionally, most of the JSON files are really large (10mb) and there are probably 500k of them to be traversed. This means my program is very slow as a result of all the Aeson-decoding. My idea was to run my `filterMatchingFile` part in parallel, but looking at the `stm-conduit` library, I can't see an obvious way to run this middle action in parallel across a handful of processors.

Can anyone suggest a way to smartly parallelize my function above using `stm-conduit` or some other means?

---

**Edit**

I realized that I could break up my `readFile -> decodeObject -> runFilterFunction` into separate parts of the `conduit` and then I could use `stm-conduit` there with a bounded channel. Maybe I'll give it a shot...

---

I ran my application with `+RTS -s` (I reconfigured it to `-N4`) and I see the following:

```
 115,961,554,600 bytes allocated in the heap
  35,870,639,768 bytes copied during GC
      56,467,720 bytes maximum residency (681 sample(s))
       1,283,008 bytes maximum slop
             145 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     108716 colls, 108716 par   76.915s  20.571s     0.0002s    0.0266s
  Gen  1       681 colls,   680 par    0.530s   0.147s     0.0002s    0.0009s

  Parallel GC work balance: 14.99% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 10 (1 bound, 9 peak workers (9 total), using -N4)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.007s elapsed)
  MUT     time   34.813s  ( 42.938s elapsed)
  GC      time   77.445s  ( 20.718s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.010s elapsed)
  Total   time  112.260s  ( 63.672s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,330,960,996 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  31.0% of total user, 67.5% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 188614
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 33
gen[1].sync: 811204
```

Comment: 1) Almost certainly nothing. You need to make the parallelism explicit (Haskell just makes it easier to parallelize your code - it doesn't do it for you).

Comment: Hi @Alec. That's exactly what I thought as well, but when I look at the process in htop, there are as many child processes as CPUs and each of them seem to be doing something (mostly "S"). That's what prompted the question. Is it doing parallel GC only (is that a thing?)?

Comment: Replace `.|` with [`buffer'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit-3.0.0/docs/Data-Conduit-Async.html#v:buffer-39-) and `runConduit` with `runCConduit`.

Comment: @erewok Parallel GC is definitely a thing. (It even says it right there in your stats!) I'm not 100% sure, but the RTS might be doing some threading for I/O management as well. I doubt much of your actual user code is parallel.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid thanks for explaining that. That's kind of what I thought might be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to run this application using `stm-conduit` with some help from the Haskell wiki on parallelism and a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340159/haskell-channels-stm-threaded-message-passing) that talks about waiting for threads to end before `main` exits.

The way it works is that I create a channel that holds all of the filenames to be operated on. Then, I fork a bunch of threads that each runs a `Conduit` with the filepath-channel as a `Source`. I track all of the child threads and wait for them to finish.

Maybe this solution will be useful for someone else?

Not all of my lower-level filter functions are present, but the gist of it is that I have a `Conduit` that tests some JSON. If it passes, then it `yield`s the `FilePath`.

Here's my main in entirety:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}


module Main where

import           Conduit                      ((.|))
import qualified Conduit                      as C
import           Control.Concurrent
import           Control.Monad                (forM_)
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class       (liftIO)
import           Control.Concurrent.STM
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (register)

import qualified Data.Conduit.TMChan          as STMChan
import           Data.Maybe                   (isJust, fromJust)
import qualified Data.Text                    as T
import           Options.Generic
import           System.Directory            (doesDirectoryExist)
import           System.Exit

import           Search


data Commands =
  Commands { searchPath  :: String
           , par         :: Maybe Int
           , project     :: Maybe T.Text
           , revision    :: Maybe T.Text
           } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance ParseRecord Commands

makeProjectFilter :: Commands -> ProjectFilter
makeProjectFilter options =
  let stdFilts = StdProjectFilters
        (ProjName <$> project options)
        (Revision <$> revision options)
  in makeProjectFilters stdFilts

main :: IO ()
main = do
  options <- getRecord "Search JSON Files"
  -- Would user like to run in parallel?
  let runner = if isJust $ par options
        then mainSTMConduit (fromJust $ par options)
        else mainStreamingConduit

  -- necessary things to search files: search path, filters to use, search dir exists
  let filterFunc = makeProjectFilter options
  searchDir <- absolutize (searchPath options)
  itExists <- doesDirectoryExist searchDir

  -- Run it if it exists
  case itExists of
    False -> putStrLn "Search Directory does not exist" >> exitWith (ExitFailure 1)
    True -> runner filterFunc searchDir

-- Single-threaded version with bounded memory usage
mainStreamingConduit :: ProjectFilter -> FilePath -> IO ()
mainStreamingConduit filterFunc searchDir = do
  C.runConduitRes $
    sourceFilesFilter filterFunc searchDir .| C.mapM_C (liftIO . putStrLn)

-- Multiple-threaded version of this program using channels from `stm-conduit`
mainSTMConduit :: Int -> ProjectFilter -> FilePath -> IO ()
mainSTMConduit nrWorkers filterFunc searchDir = do
  children <- newMVar []
  inChan <- atomically $ STMChan.newTBMChan 16
  _ <- forkIO . C.runResourceT $ do
         _ <- register $ atomically $ STMChan.closeTBMChan inChan
         C.runConduitRes $ C.sourceDirectoryDeep False searchDir .| STMChan.sinkTBMChan inChan True
  forM_ [1..nrWorkers] (\_ -> forkChild children $ runConduitChan inChan filterFunc)
  waitForChildren children
  return ()


runConduitChan :: STMChan.TBMChan FilePath -> ProjectFilter -> IO ()
runConduitChan inChan filterFunc = do
  C.runConduitRes $
       STMChan.sourceTBMChan inChan
       .| parseProject filterFunc
       .| C.mapM_C (liftIO . putStrLn)

waitForChildren :: MVar [MVar ()] -> IO ()
waitForChildren children = do
  cs <- takeMVar children
  case cs of
    []   -> return ()
    m:ms -> do
      putMVar children ms
      takeMVar m
      waitForChildren children

forkChild :: MVar [MVar ()] -> IO () -> IO ThreadId
forkChild children io = do
  mvar <- newEmptyMVar
  childs <- takeMVar children
  putMVar children (mvar:childs)
  forkFinally io (\_ -> putMVar mvar ())
```

Note: I'm using `stm-conduit 3.0.0` with `conduit 1.12.1`, which is why I needed to include the boolean argument:

```
STMChan.sinkTBMChan inChan True
```

In version `4.0.0` of `stm-conduit`, this function automatically closes the channel, so the boolean argument has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Prompted by Michael Snoyman on Haskell Cafe, who pointed out that my first version was not truly taking advantage of Conduit's streaming capabilities, I rewrote my Conduit version of the application (without using stm-conduit). This was a large improvement: my first Conduit version was operating over all data and I didn't realize this.

I also increased the nursery size and this increased my productivity by doing garbage collection less frequently.

My revised function ended up looking like this:

```
module Search where

import           Conduit               ((.|))
import qualified Conduit               as C
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class   (MonadIO, liftIO)
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadResource)
import qualified Data.ByteString       as B
import           Data.List             (isPrefixOf)
import           Data.Maybe            (fromJust, isJust)
import           System.Path.NameManip (guess_dotdot, absolute_path)
import           System.FilePath       (addTrailingPathSeparator, normalise)
import           System.Directory      (getHomeDirectory)

import           Filters


sourceFilesFilter :: (MonadResource m, MonadIO m) => ProjectFilter -> FilePath -> C.ConduitM () String m ()
sourceFilesFilter projFilter dirname' =
    C.sourceDirectoryDeep False dirname'
    .| parseProject projFilter

parseProject :: (MonadResource m, MonadIO m) => ProjectFilter -> C.ConduitM FilePath String m ()
parseProject (ProjectFilter filterFunc) = do
  C.awaitForever go
  where
    go path' = do
      bytes <- liftIO $ B.readFile path'
      let isProj = validProject bytes
      when (isJust isProj) $ do
        let proj' = fromJust isProj
        when (filterFunc proj') $ C.yield path'
```

My main just runs the conduit and prints those that pass the filter:

```
mainStreamingConduit :: IO ()
mainStreamingConduit = do
  options <- getRecord "Search JSON Files"
  let filterFunc = makeProjectFilter options
  searchDir <- absolutize (searchPath options)
  itExists <- doesDirectoryExist searchDir
  case itExists of
    False -> putStrLn "Search Directory does not exist" >> exitWith (ExitFailure 1)
    True -> C.runConduitRes $ sourceFilesFilter filterFunc searchDir .| C.mapM_ (liftIO . putStrLn)
```

I run it like this (without the stats, typically):

```
stack exec search-json -- --searchPath $FILES --name NAME +RTS -s -A32m -n4m
```

Without increasing nursery size, I get a productivity around 30%. With the above, however, it looks like this:

```
  72,308,248,744 bytes allocated in the heap
     733,911,752 bytes copied during GC
       7,410,520 bytes maximum residency (8 sample(s))
         863,480 bytes maximum slop
             187 MB total memory in use (27 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       580 colls,   580 par    2.731s   0.772s     0.0013s    0.0105s
  Gen  1         8 colls,     7 par    0.163s   0.044s     0.0055s    0.0109s

  Parallel GC work balance: 35.12% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 10 (1 bound, 9 peak workers (9 total), using -N4)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.006s elapsed)
  MUT     time   26.155s  ( 31.602s elapsed)
  GC      time    2.894s  (  0.816s elapsed)
  EXIT    time   -0.003s  (  0.008s elapsed)
  Total   time   29.048s  ( 32.432s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,764,643,665 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  90.0% of total user, 97.5% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 3494
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 15527
gen[1].sync: 177
```

I'd still like to figure out how to parallelize the `filterProj . parseJson . readFile` part, but for now I'm satisfied with this.

Answer (score 1):

From your program description, there is no reason for it to have increasing memory usage. I think it was accidental memory leak from missed lazy computation. This can be easily detected by heap profiling: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#hp2ps-rendering-heap-profiles-to-postscript. Other possible reason is that runtime does not release all memory back to OS. Until some threshold, it will keep holding to memory proportional to the largest file processed. This may look as a memory leak if tracked through process RSS size.

`-A32m` option increases nursery size. It lets your program allocate more memory before garbage collection is triggered. Stats shows that very little memory is retained during GC, so less often it happens, more time program spends doing actual work.